# Display the value '??' in strings.xml

Tags: android

I have a little problem but I have no answer. I use the strings.xml to store all texts from my application. If i want save the next value : '??' so I have an error when I execute my app.

```
<string name="unknown_text">??</string>

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'unknown_text' with value '??').
```

Is there a solution to save this value in xml or I must use setText() for all widgets which need it ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<string name="questions">\??</string>`

check [FormattingAndStyling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) and this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/vV3A9nkbGPc) for more detail.

Comment: Oh yeah !! That's perfect. I don't understand why i didn't test to escape it. Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

It's good habit to always quote whole string:

```
<string name="unknown_text">"??"</string>
```

Comment: Never known this before :) thanx

Comment: Why is it good habit ? I've never used quote in xml and the doc precises the 2 ways are good ...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: From the doc :


`<string name="good_example">"This'll work"</string>
<string name="good_example_2">This\'ll also work</string>`


Both are good example (with and without quote)